# Using the gridviewdraganddrop breaks when using the BufferedStore in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs

I'm using the 'gridviewdragdrop' plugin with my 'Ext.grid.Pane'l. I also have the Panel hooked up to a 'Ext.data.BufferedStore' and when I drag a row and drop it any where in the table I get this error message:

'Uncaught Error: insert method may not be called on a buffered store - the store is a map of remote data'

Any techniques to work around this?

Comment: No. As it says, you can't add/remove/move items in a buffered store.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking if there were 'Any techniques to work around this?'

Comment: What do you mean by "techniques"? The store doesn't support it, because once you start changing things locally it throws off the buffering/paging and it doesn't know what to fetch from the server.

Comment: I was looking for ideas on how to work around this.